# How to allow a group to access a folder?

Tags: permission

I want to allow the _www group to write to a folder.

I clicked on the folder to go to the "Get Info".

At the bottom there is a "Sharing & Permissions" section with a "+" to add users. However it does not show any of the system groups such as _www.

Is there a way to enable showing hidden users and group in the GUI?
Or do I have to do it via command-line instead?
It seems the GUI allows to set permissions for several users and group, which I like, while the command I believe only allow 1 owner and 1 group?

Comment: +1 because you made me sit down and figure out *why* Apple left out the standard commands and what to do about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apple hides anything it considers a "system" user or group from the GUI.  There's probably some way to disable that, but I generally use the command line for system-related stuff.

The command line version comes in two flavors:  there is a basic permissions structure with a single owner, a singe group, and everyone else, then there are POSIX ACLs.   Interestingly, Apple took the route of modifying `chmod` to support ACLs instead of shipping the standard `getfacl` and `setfacl` tools.

```
$ sudo chmod +a 'group:_www allow add_file,add_subdirectory,list,search,delete_child' /webroot
```

You may also want the `file_inherit` and `directory_inherit` permissions to apply the ACL to created files/directories.  See `chmod(1)` for more details.

The `-a` option to `chmod` removes ACL entries.

Comment: +1 just a small clarification, do you know if/why `sudo chmod -R +a '<permissions>' /webroot` will give permissions to all subfolders, but not to `webroot` folder itself? because that's what happened when i tried it.